# Variable value in inspector is not updating automatically?

Tags: unity, unityscript

Something weird is happening when I change a variable value in script and hit play the var value doesn't update I have to reset the script in inspector. Is this normal? Aren't the values suppose to update when we hit play?

*The Simple Code I used to test this:*

```
var a:int=0;

function Start () {
print(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The editor serializes the value for what you've set in the inspector prior to changing it in code. It doesn't matter if you change the value of `a` in script. The editor only cares about the serialized values, after the object is created.

When you hit play it takes the value you've set in the inspector.

Comment: That means I have to change the value in inspector every time I change a variable in my script and if I reset the script from inspector it will remove the assigned game objects from variable so I have to add them again......that's  annoying...

Comment: @helpMePlz Mark the field with [NonSerialized], although that might cause issues later down the line if you ever *do* want to serialize it.

Comment: If im not mistaken you can reset one value as well, just right click it.I wouldn't set it to non serialized cause then the inspector doesn't catch it. Also @helpMePlz stop changing public values in code! Create a prefab instead so you can apply the changes to all instances.

Comment: I believe you can signal to the editor "I've changed something with this object through script, please re-serialize it so that change gets saved/carried into play mode" — this used tp be done by calling [SetDirty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html), but the method has changed since then as described at the link.

Comment: That only helps if you are doing actual inspector script though. I think OP is talking about values that are initialized at deceleration.

Comment: "deceleration"? Do you mean deserialization? You can signal to the editor that you've changed serialized data when you're deserializing in-editor too.

Comment: Declaration * . typo

Answer (score -1):

I found a very simple solution: initializing the variables inside the `Start()` function.

Like such:

```
var a:int=0;

function Start () {
    a = 0;
    print(a);
}
```

Comment: It supposed to be a comment.... I can't delete it

Comment: You do realize that you can not set the value in the inspector now, right? Also I suggest you move away from UnityScript and use C# instead. UnityScript will be become obsolete and 99% of the material is done in C#.

Comment: Converting from .js files to .cs files is relatively easy. I did it once. The regex replacements
`s/function ([A-z0-9]*)():([A-z]*)/\2 \1` and `s/var ([A-z0-9]*):([A-z]*)/\2 \1` (assuming no symbols in variable or type names) are pretty much all you need, although you will need to go in and add "void" to all the functions that don't return anything. (Also, `\1` might have to be `$1` depending on your editor's implementation of regex capture groups).